# Link a macro to a commandbar button in an Addin

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to link a macro to a commandbar button in an Addin. I put it under the onaction segment of the command button.

I tried several ways of writing the macro name even set-up a reference.

Cannot run 'serialbutton.xlam!getserial'.

> The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled

```vb
Sub Auto_Open() 'Or Private Sub Workboo_Open() in ThisWorkbook
Dim CmdBar As CommandBar
Dim CmdBarMenu As CommandBarControl
Dim CmdBarMenuItem As CommandBarControl

Set CmdBar = Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar")
Set CmdBarMenu = CmdBar.Controls("Tools")   ' Index 6

On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
CmdBarMenu.Controls("Get Serial No").Delete 'Just in case a button with same name already exists
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
On Error GoTo 0

Set CmdBarMenuItem = CmdBarMenu.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
With CmdBarMenuItem
     .Caption = "Get Serial No"
     .OnAction = "'getserial'"  'Name of the sub it will call when button is pushed
     .FaceId = 215 'assigns an icon to the dropdown
End With

End Sub


Sub getserial()
    'macro to open file on central location and get serial number
    Dim serialNo As String
    Dim actual As String
    Dim serialfile As String
    'Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim wb As Object

    'Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("somefile")
    Application.Run "'" & ActiveWorkbook.Name & "'!GeneratSerialNumber"
    serialNo = Cells(1, 1).Value
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Cells(1, 1).Value = serialNo
End Sub
```

Comment: What if you get rid of the single quotes?

Comment: I still get the same error:

Comment: Cannot run the macro 'serialbutton.xlam!getserial'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.